# Delete empty xml tags from file through SED in unix

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed

I have one xml file which is having empty tags like

```
<action></action>
```

need to delete these tags from xml file.

tried:

```
cat file1.xml | sed 's/\<action\>\<\/action\>//g'
```

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Are you content with the empty lines left after empty tags are deleted? In general it is better to use specialized xml tools for XML than rely on ugly hacks.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the start and end tags are on separate lines?  Is that still empty or is the `\n` significant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
sed -E 's#<([^>]+)></\1>##g'
```

- `#` is the `s` (substitution) delimiter as the input contains `/`
- `<([^>]+)>` matches `<` then the substring upto next `>` is matched and put in captured group 1, `>` matches literal `>`
- `</\1>` matches `<`, then a `/` followed by the captured group 1, then a `>`
- the whole match is replaced by null string, globally (`g`) i.e. all instances in a line

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's#<([^>]+)></\1>##g' <<<'<action></action><action>ok</action>'
<action>ok</action>
```

---

**Edit:**

If you just want to remove only `action` tags:

```
sed -E 's#<(action)></\1>##g'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @heemayl, but its deleting other blank tags also like 
"<job></job>"  
please advise

Comment: @joy Check my edits.